# Crystal reports The parameter is incorrect C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a report that has two parameters:  ponumber and receiptno.  I'm trying to call the report from a C# page where the parameter values are passed in via the URL.  When I call the report, I get an error "The parameter is incorrect", but can't figure out why.  I've done a variety of code changes based on what I found online, because at first the Report Viewer said there were no parameters, so this approach seems to be *better*, but doesn't work.

My code:

```
string ponumber =  Request.QueryString["ponumber"].ToString();
string receiptno = Request.QueryString["receiptno"].ToString();

    // Put Away Report


    CrystalReportSource CrystalReportSource1 = new CrystalReportSource();
    CrystalReportViewer CrystalReportViewer1 = new CrystalReportViewer();



    ParameterFields paramFields1 = new ParameterFields();
    ParameterFields paramFields2 = new ParameterFields();
    ParameterField paramField1 = new ParameterField();
    ParameterField paramField2 = new ParameterField();
    ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue2 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

    paramField1.Name = "@ponumber";
    paramDiscreteValue1.Value = ponumber;
    paramField1.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue1);
    paramField1.HasCurrentValue = true;
    paramFields1.Add(paramField1);

    paramField2.Name = "@receiptno";
    paramDiscreteValue2 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();  // <-- This line is added
    paramDiscreteValue2.Value = receiptno;
    paramField2.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue2);
    paramField2.HasCurrentValue = true;
    paramFields2.Add(paramField2);

    CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields1;
    CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields2;

    TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName =   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportServerName"];
    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportDatabaseName"];
    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportUserID"];
    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportPassword"];

    TableLogOnInfos infos = new TableLogOnInfos();
    infos.Add(logOnInfo);
    CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo = infos;

    maindiv.Controls.Add(CrystalReportSource1);
    maindiv.Controls.Add(CrystalReportViewer1);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CrystalReportSource1;
    CrystalReportViewer1.EnableParameterPrompt = false;
    CrystalReportSource1.Report.FileName = "Report3.rpt";
    CrystalReportSource1.EnableCaching = false;
    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another answer on SO that got me over the hump.  I replaced 13 lines of code with:

```
CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(0, ponumber);
CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(1, receiptno);
```

[Passing Values to a Crystal Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622498/passing-values-to-a-crystal-report)

Rather than build the collection manually, it looks like the source has a different method to setting parameter values.  I suspect my first attempt was to create parameters on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Crystal Reports, but a few things jumped out at me, namely here:

```
    CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields1;
    CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields2;
```

You are overwriting the ParameterFieldInfo collection on the second line, so effectively `paramFields1` never gets sent to the report.  Instead, I think you want to *add* to the collection.  I have modified your code to do this (and removed the unnecessary lines):

```
    string ponumber = Request.QueryString["ponumber"].ToString();
    string receiptno = Request.QueryString["receiptno"].ToString();

    // Put Away Report

    CrystalReportSource CrystalReportSource1 = new CrystalReportSource();
    CrystalReportViewer CrystalReportViewer1 = new CrystalReportViewer();

    ParameterField paramField1 = new ParameterField();
    ParameterField paramField2 = new ParameterField();
    ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue2 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

    paramField1.Name = "@ponumber";
    paramDiscreteValue1.Value = ponumber;
    paramField1.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue1);
    paramField1.HasCurrentValue = true;

    paramField2.Name = "@receiptno";
    paramDiscreteValue2.Value = receiptno;
    paramField2.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue2);
    paramField2.HasCurrentValue = true;

    CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo.Add(paramField1);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo.Add(paramField2);

    TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportServerName"];
    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportDatabaseName"];
    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportUserID"];
    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportPassword"];

    TableLogOnInfos infos = new TableLogOnInfos();
    infos.Add(logOnInfo);
    CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo = infos;

    maindiv.Controls.Add(CrystalReportSource1);
    maindiv.Controls.Add(CrystalReportViewer1);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CrystalReportSource1;
    CrystalReportViewer1.EnableParameterPrompt = false;
    CrystalReportSource1.Report.FileName = "Report3.rpt";
    CrystalReportSource1.EnableCaching = false;
    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks @Slippery Pete. I believe I had changed that once upon a time.  Seems like any change I make, Crystal just doesn't like that parameter.  I did notice that the report parameters are set up like strings, but the parameters are getting sent like numbers.  Might be a red herring, but something I'm checking into next.  This should be *simple*