# Missing parameter error in crystal

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

I am running the crystal reports. But I am getting the following errors:
"Missing parameter values"
"Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

All the parameters are being passed to the front end. Provider is also correct.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you post your code? How *exactly* are you trying to pass the parameters to the report?

Comment: hey... i dont know the code as it being passed by the web developer. I am only in charge of databases. Is there any other way?

Comment: The parameters are being passed to Crystal via the program.  Without seeing the code, there's no way of telling how those parameters are being passed, or if the code that is invoking the report is correct. See this link as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200234/crystal-reports-the-parameter-is-incorrect-c-sharp

Comment: web developer says that paramters being passed are correct...... Is there any upgradation issue. we have upgraded crystal 11 to 13

Comment: don't know - i'm using crystal 11.  i would expect backwards compatibility for newer versions though.  How would your developer know the parameters are being passed correctly when crystal can't see them?  Seems like a disconnect where you work.

Comment: previously it was working.. with the same parameters and this was the existing rpt ... I have just changed the data source. But the parameters remains the same. Everythinh is same.

Comment: Without seeing code, screenshots, or something with a little more detail, I don't know what to tell you.  It seems to me the application is not passing parameters to crystal correctly (or at all).  But if we can't see code, we probably won't be able to help.